# Aparece un campo file (input file) sin haberlo agregado, en laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-excel

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en `Laravel 5.4`, después de agregar `Laravel Excel` en el sitio en linea (server on-line) me aparece un campo `input-file`, pero en local (server desarrollo) no aparece este campo.

**Vista welcome** (default laravel):

```html
!doctype html><br/>
html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}"><br/>
head><br/>
    meta charset="utf-8"><br/>
    meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><br/>
    meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><br/>

    <title>Terminals</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css">
```

**Vista en el servidor de producción**:

```html
html><br/>
head><br/>
title>Upload files</title><br/>
/head><br/>
body><br/>
form method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""><br/>
input type=text name=path><input type="file" name="files"><input type=submit value="Up"><br/>
/form><br/>
/body><br/>
/html><br/>
!doctype html><br/>
html lang="en"><br/>
head><br/>
    meta charset="utf-8"><br/>
    meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><br/>
    meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><br/>

    <title>Terminals</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css">
```

Comment: No es necesario agregar un salto de línea `<br/>` despues de cada etiqueta `HTML`, no aporta ningún beneficio y ensucia el código.

Comment: ¿podrías agregar una captura de pantalla donde se aprecie un poco de contexto (no solo el campo)?

Comment: Podrías agregar como se llega a esa vista. ¿Desde un controlador? ¿Desde el web.php?